# Create a table on specific filegroup in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

So, this process I have is actually on SAS but the SQL syntax should be the same I need to put it on the filegroup STAGING_DATA_FG02, so I added as you can see below a line of code I thought would help but it is not reading it, is it the correct syntax?

```sql
CREATE TABLE DBO.TBL
AS
SELECT 
  input(&varFileDate, BEST22.) as FileDate  ,
  TRIM(SSN) as SSN              , 
  ExmDescription                , 
  Status                        ,
  ScaledScore                   ,
  ExamDate          
  FROM DBO.TBL_A
  ORDER BY SSN
  ON [STAGING_DATA_FG02] WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE);
```

Comment: The syntax is invalid for SQL Server as it doesn't offer the option to create a table from a query. The closest SQL Server has is `select into table`.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for creating a table from a query in SQL Server is select-into:

```
SELECT 
  input(&varFileDate, BEST22.) as FileDate  ,
  TRIM(SSN) as SSN              , 
  ExmDescription                , 
  Status                        ,
  ScaledScore                   ,
  ExamDate           
INTO DBO.TBL ON [STAGING_DATA_FG02]
FROM DBO.TBL_A
```

Note: The ON clause is only available in this syntax since SQL Server 2016 SP2. AFAIK, there is no way to use `WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)` with this syntax.

Comment: I think I should have been more specific with my question, the DBO.TBL_A table is created on SAS, and we are using the backbone of that SAS created table to build it in SQL server. So the DBO.TBL is the actual table that is generated in SQL Server. I cannot specify on the SAS script which filegroup to use. I think maybe putting this on a SAS tag may help.